# Identify Wireless or GPRS network using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How do I identify the network type the phone is operating in (wireless, or GPRS) using C#?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.networkinformation.networkinterface.getinternetinterfacetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

`NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterfaceType` returns a `NetworkInterfaceType` enum you can match on.